# how set individual user accounts and enable-migrations in mvc vs 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

Recently I have installed vs 2017, before that I utilized vs 2012 and when I created web application mvc , I didn't have any problem on choosing  individual user accounts icon so I can get my classes like AccountController.cs and so on. 
but now after creating mvc application ,I can't get window of choosing individual user accounts, so when I type code like this in package manager console:

- PM> enable-migrations

I get this error :

> No context type was found in the assembly 'vidly'

I know why I get this error because I don't have any dbcontex class, but I don't no how create identitymodel.cs which was default model of individual user accounts option and inherits from identitydbcontex.So how can I handle this in vs2017?

Comment: Right click on Model folder add->newitem->data->ADO.NET Entity data model

Comment: @CoolJK this give me models of ef and codefirst, I want get identitymodel.cs which was default  option individual user accounts option.

Comment: You need to choose none and then install the Identity Nuget package. See [here](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/47/aspnet-identity-in-aspnet-mvc-50---customizing-applicationuser-table-and-using-single-dbcontext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot  I got that this feature in vs 2017 has totally removed, but you can add it by your self.
Here: [individual user accounts in vs 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)
Hope its useful for others.